# How can I mark a class in Quarkus ARC and/or IntelliJ IDEA to not be a bean?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, quarkus

I have a simple helper class in a Quarkus project. It takes some arguments to construct, and IntelliJ IDEA warns "Unsatisfied dependency: no bean matches the injection point". In CDI, I have to annotate the constructor with `@Inject` to get constructor injection, but that's not necessary with Quarkus.

I can suppress the warning, sure, but as this happens more often, is there a more elegant way to tell Quarkus that this is *not* a bean? And doesn't Quarkus still do some magic with my class, even though it's completely unnecessary?

Comment: I have personally also seen IntelliJ IDEA producing CDI-related warnings in Quarkus projects, even though the class in question definitely wasn't a bean. If you're sure your class isn't a bean (doesn't have a bean defining annotation, doesn't have an observer method, doesn't have a producer method, perhaps a few other conditions -- Quarkus tends to turn a class into a bean whenever it has a CDI-related annotation anywhere), it's just IDEA's mistake.

Comment: I would suggest opening an issue on the JetBrains issue tracker

Comment: Please raise this issue at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA , and provide a small code snippet. Thank you!

Comment: created https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-275211

Comment: The issue was marked a duplicate to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-256608.
The bugfix "will be available in next bug-fix release 2021.3.1"